# Remove element from a JsonObject

Tags: java, json

I would like to keep the first additionalProperties ( there are several additionalProperties in different levels) and other ones remove:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "description": "Test.",
  "additionalProperties": true,
  "properties": {
    "spec": {
      "type": "object",
      "description": "reference spec",
      "additionalProperties": true,
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "spec1": {
      "type": "array",
      "description": "reference spec2",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "description": "specblabla.",
        "additionalProperties": true,
        "properties": {
```

```java
public void printJsonObject(JsonObject jsonObj)
{
    jsonObj.keySet().forEach(keyStr ->
    {
        Object keyvalue = jsonObj.get(keyStr);
        System.out.println("key: "+ keyStr + " value: " + keyvalue);
           if(keyStr.equals("additionalProperties"))
           {
            jsonObj.remove("additionalProperties");
           }

           //for nested objects iteration if required
           if (keyvalue instanceof JsonObject)
           {
               printJsonObject((JsonObject)keyvalue);
           }
       });
}
```

How to this in java, I tried with this code, but give an error that I cannot exclude element due interaction.
I tried to walk through json but couldn`t remove it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error.

Comment: What is `JsonObject`, i.e. which JSON library are you using?

Comment: you probably are getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` as its fail-fast. As the json doesn't look uniformly structured, you could just save the paths of the entries you wish to remove (f.e, adding them to a List), and delete them after the loop.